# Why don't these rectangles appear?

Tags: highcharts

I'm having a lot of trouble with something that should be pretty straightforward.  I can't get rectangles with world coordinates (time on the x-axis and price on the y-axis) to appear:

```
chart.renderer.rect(chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1432810800),chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(1.089965),chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(10800),chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(0.0032400000000001317), 0)
  .attr({fill: '#FFFF0F', stroke: 'green', 'stroke-width':1, zIndex:4})
  .add()
```

The full chart is http://jsfiddle.net/36tk5jsa/.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the solution is to compute the width and height like this:

```
    chart.renderer.rect(chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1431716400000),chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(1.14505),chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1431896400000)-chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(1431716400000),chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(1.144735)-chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(1.14505), 0)
      .attr({fill: '#FF0FFF', stroke: 'red', 'stroke-width':1, zIndex:4})
      .add()
```

That is, you have to convert the two coordinates to pixels and then subtract to get the width or height.  (It's not clear to me why you can't do the subtraction first and then convert to pixels, since we are talking about a relative change which should be the same in either coordinate system.  On the other hand, I no longer care. :-)

Comment: You can't, since `toPixels` returns pixels position relative to the actual extremes. For example yAxis has scale 100-1000, and rect should be 120-130 in yAxis units. When substracting values, it's 10units. Now when trying to use `toPixels(10)`, it will return pixel position **outside** the actual range.